# How to show proper alt text using the default WordPress Gutenberg block?

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I am having issues showing the default alt text. For example, my images in a WordPress post show up with the "title + number" rather than the original alt text I set in the image. For example, I have a WordPress post titled "How to Edit WordPress theme?" with 3 images. The 2nd image has an alt text "install and activate the theme". But it shows "How to Edit WordPress theme? 2".

It is a client's website and I don't know if he made any changes to the site's coding. How do I show the default alt text using the default Gutenberg WordPress image block - once I hover it will show the alt text I set initially in the block.

What are the ways to do this?

I tried keeping the title and the alt text the same for an image. It did not work.